# Did I set my map variable properly to a fetched json?

Tags: javascript, json, object, dictionary, fetch

I have some code below to transform a fetched json into string and remove the braces and parse it into a map variable:

```
let result = '';
let map = [];

fetch(link)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    result = JSON.stringify(json); //json here is like [{'a':1,'a2':2},{'b':11,'b2':12}]
    result = result.substring(1, result.length - 1);
    map = JSON.parse(result);
  }).catch(function(ex) {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex);
  });
```

I've tried to simply set `map=json` but it both gives out the same error that I have duplicate keys for the map.

If I hard code my `map` variable to lets say `[{'id':1,code: 007},{'id':2, code:014}]` it works. I've tried to log `result` after changing it to a string and its exactly as the example. So in other words, setting `map=json` should work in the first place.

I think I might be missing something. What is it?

**EDIT #1**:

```
fetch(link)
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(json) {
  setData(json);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = json;
}).catch(function(ex) {
  console.log('parsing failed', ex);
});


function setData(json) {
  map = json;
}
```

I've tried the solution given by Naomik except without the `response ok` part.
I'm still receiving the same error as `map = json`. Any help with this?

Comment: What does the `json` argument in the second `.then()` contain? Isn't it already a string? If you strip the square brackets off `[{'a':1,'a2':2},{'b':11,'b2':12}]`, which incidentally you can do more easily with `.slice(1,-1)`, you end up with something that isn't valid JSON.

Comment: You're doing the same thing you just moved the `map = ...` to another function. You will **never** be able to access the data *outside* of the callback chain. Read ["How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and ["Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Those questions have hundreds of upvotes because they are extremely common. Understanding asynchronous programming is an uphill climb, but once you get the hang of it, it's easy.

Comment: I'm still in the process of reading it, but I kind of understand the concept of asynchronous calls. Btw as I've mentioned in my post, setting `map` to a sample hard coded json data worked. Eg `map = [{"a":1},{"a":2}]` works but `map = json` doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set a variable like that in an asynchronous handler and expect it to be set outside of the handler. More about that here: ["How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

I would've just marked your question as a duplicate of that one, but there's other issues with your code so I'm gonna address those now

In your second `.then` call, you are attempting to process `json` but you're doing it incorrectly

```
// Why exactly are you re-stringifying the data we just parsed ?
result = JSON.stringify(json);

// ... wtf ?
result = result.substring(1, result.length - 1);

// Same as above, any vars you set here cannot be read outside of the callback.
// This won't work like you expect (see the related question I linked above)
map = JSON.parse(result);
```

Remember, JSON is just a *string* that represents your data, nothing else

- `JSON.parse` will take a json *string* and turn it into data.
- `JSON.stringify` will take data and turn it into a json string.

---

This example might help you a bit

```
fetch(link).then(function(response) {
  if (response.ok)
    // read JSON response and parse it
    return response.json() 
  else
    // response is not OK, throw error
    throw Error(response.status + " " + response.statusText)
})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log("Your data has arrived!")
  console.log("Do something here with your data")
  doSomething(data)
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err.message)
})

function doSomething(data) {
  console.log("Here's your data:", data);
}
```

Comment: FYI the OP uses https://github.com/github/fetch which already does all the parsing. Naming is unfortunate in the samples provided on the github page.

Comment: @Tomalak ah thanks. So it's safe to just pull out the `.then(json => JSON.parse(json)` and skip right to `.then(data => ...)` ?

Comment: @Tomalak thanks. Yeah very unfortunate naming. That's definitely one of my biggest pet peeves; when someone names a var `json` that's not actually a JSON string.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. It really grinds my gears. ;) I had an answer ready that explained that (and the return-values-from-async-functions bit),  but you beat me to it by a minute or so.

Comment: @naomik , I've tried your solution. See the edited part of my question. I'm still receiving the same errors

Comment: Yes because you're still trying to set `map`. I already said you cannot do that. Read the questions I linked in the comment to your question.